# Local database is blank when I restart my app

Tags: iphone, sqlite

```
    [arrMessages removeAllObjects];
    [arrMessages addObjectsFromArray:[appDelegate.skdb lookupAllForSQL:@"Select * from tblMessage where isActive = 'T'"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrMessages);
    if(arrMessages.count > 0)
    {
        [appDelegate showAlert:@"From DB"];
    }
    else
    {
        [appDelegate showAlert:@"Go To Live"];
        [appDelegate.skdb insertArray:arrMessages forTable:@"tblMessage"];
    }
```

When I run my application for the first time It goes to live and insert in local DB.Then every time it comes from Local. This is fine. But then I quit application from background. Then start application again. It goes to live. It should fetch data from local DB.

Comment: what exactly is this "local DB"?  Core Data?  A mutable array?

Comment: Where you are writing this code?

Comment: I got this problem resolved..... Actually My data was coming from DB but... array was not initialized.... A Silly Mistake has taken my half an hour